# How to fix this error, next js + firebase + Zeit

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using firebase in Nextjs app, it works perfectly fine on production but 
while deploying to Zeit I am getting this error!

```
 ./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js
                          Module not found: Can't resolve 'request' in '/tmp/6d82ffed/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist'
2019-07-08T17:56:01.203Z  > Build error occurred
2019-07-08T17:56:01.203Z  Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
                              at Object.build [as default] (/tmp/6d82ffed/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:192:15)
                              at <anonymous>
                              at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

How can I resolve this.

I checked the github issues and I found its an open issue with no solution provided yet

https://github.com/zeit/now-cli/issues/1830

is the issue link!